# Antd v4: How to add nesting in <Form.List>?

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am trying to create a custom grid like structure.
The structure will consist of various rows and each row can have multiple columns. And each column will have 1-2 form fields.

With Antd v4.2.0, we have `<Form.List />` component with helps us to create dynamic form.

I tried using it and it was fine for the dynamic row part, but I am unable to figure out how can I create mutliple columns ie `<Form.List>` inside `<Form.List>`

I can create this grid manually as well but I want to leverage the form validation as well within this grid.

Visual representation for what I am trying to create:

[image]

Comment: did got any work around?

Comment: Only workaround I am thinking off is not to use <Form.List /> and try with old school nested arrays: array of columns inside array of rows. @Jaison.

Comment: Thanks, I am also finally going back to the old school method, hope they will come up with a solution later...

Answer (score 24):

To add a nested `<Form.List>` element inside another `<Form.List>` just add the nested list inside the outer list loop like any other nested `<Form.Item>`. The trick is to set the nested `<Form.List>` name property correctly, using the format: `<Form.List name={[field.name, 'nested-input-name']}>`.

As an example, let's extend the dynamic form example from the official documentation (https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-dynamic-form-item) with a nested list. The original example adds fields for "first name" and "last name", so we'll add a nested list for "nicknames".

```
import { Form, Input, Button, Space } from 'antd';
import { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log('Received values of form:', values);
  };

  return (
    <Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map(field => (
                <>
                    <Space key={field.key} style={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: 8 }} align="start">
                      <Form.Item
                        {...field}
                        name={[field.name, 'first']}
                        fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'first']}
                        rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing first name' }]}
                      >
                        <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                      </Form.Item>
                      <Form.Item
                        {...field}
                        name={[field.name, 'last']}
                        fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'last']}
                        rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing last name' }]}
                      >
                        <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                      </Form.Item>

                      <MinusCircleOutlined
                        onClick={() => {
                          remove(field.name);
                        }}
                      />
                    </Space>
                
                    <Form.List name={[field.name, 'nicknames']}>
                        {(nicknames, { add, remove }) => {
                          return (
                            <div>
                              {nicknames.map(nickname => (
                                <Space key={nickname.key} align="start">
                                  <Form.Item
                                    {...nickname}
                                    name={[nickname.name, 'nickname']}
                                    fieldKey={[nickname.fieldKey, 'nickname']}
                                    rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing nickname' }]}
                                  >
                                    <Input placeholder="Nickname" />
                                  </Form.Item>

                                  <MinusCircleOutlined
                                    onClick={() => {
                                      remove(nickname.name);
                                    }}
                                  />
                                </Space>
                              ))}

                              <Form.Item>
                                <Button
                                  type="dashed"
                                  onClick={() => {
                                    add();
                                  }}
                                  block
                                >
                                  <PlusOutlined /> Add nickname
                                </Button>
                              </Form.Item>
                            </div>
                          );
                        }}
                    </Form.list>
                </>
              ))}

              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  block
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, mountNode);
```

I'm keeping with the single component style of the official documentation, but you would probably want to break this up into smaller components in a real application.